# i am not able to add product through admin module

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

this is the full error:-

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "PRODUCTID"; SQL statement:
    insert into Product (productId, productCategory, productCondition, productDescription, productManufacturer, productName, productPrice, productStatus, unitInStock) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-190]] with root cause
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "PRODUCTID"; SQL statement:
    insert into Product (productId, productCategory, productCondition, productDescription, productManufacturer, productName, productPrice, productStatus, unitInStock) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-193]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
        at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:311)
        at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:784)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:151)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
        at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98)
        at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
        at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:344)
        at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:158)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:624)
        at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeUpdate(CommandRemote.java:191)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:157)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:143)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2757)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3268)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:78)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:304)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:615)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:608)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:604)
        at com.emusicstore.dao.impl.ProductDaoImpl.addProduct(ProductDaoImpl.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.addProduct(Unknown Source)
        at com.emusicstore.controller.AdminController.addProductPost(AdminController.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1033)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



my add product page:-



    `<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp" %>


    <div class="container-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Add Product</h1>

                <p class="lead">Fill the below information to add a product:</p>
            </div>

            <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/productInventory/addProduct" commandName="product" method="Post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">



            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label> <form:errors path="productName" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" />
                <form:input path="productName" id="name" class="form-Control"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCategory" id="category"
                                                                 value="instrument" />Instrument</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCategory" id="category"
                                                                 value="record" />Record</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCategory" id="category"
                                                                 value="accessory" />Accessory</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <form:textarea path="productDescription" id="description" class="form-Control"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price</label>  <form:errors path="productPrice" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" />
                <form:input path="productPrice" id="price" class="form-Control"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="condition">Condition</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCondition" id="condition"
                                                                 value="new" />New</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCondition" id="condition"
                                                                 value="used" />Used</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="status">Status</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productStatus" id="status"
                                                                 value="active" />Active</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productStatus" id="status"
                                                                 value="inactive" />Inactive</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="unitInStock">Unit In Stock</label>  <form:errors path="unitInStock"
                                                                             cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" />
                <form:input path="unitInStock" id="unitInStock" class="form-Control"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer</label>
                <form:input path="productManufacturer" id="manufacturer" class="form-Control"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="productImage">Upload Picture</label>
                <form:input id="productImage" path="productImage" type="file" class="form:input-large" />
            </div>

            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            <a href="<c:url value="/admin/productInventory" />" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
            </form:form>


            <%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp" %>

`

my controller maping:-


@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/productInventory/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addProductPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("product") Product product, BindingResult result,
                             HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "addProduct";
    }

    productDao.addProduct(product);

    MultipartFile productImage = product.getProductImage();
    String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    path = Paths.get(rootDirectory + "\\WEB-INF\\resources\\images\\" + product.getProductId() + ".png");

    if (productImage != null && !productImage.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Product image saving failed", e);
        }
    }

    return "redirect:/admin/productInventory";
}

my model Product.java





package com.emusicstore.model;




import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by Le on 1/2/2016.
 */

@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int productId;

    @Id
    @NotEmpty (message = "The product name must not be null.")
    private String productName;
    private String productCategory;
    private String productDescription;

    @Min(value = 0, message = "The product price must no be less then zero.")
    private double productPrice;
    private String productCondition;
    private String productStatus;

    @Min(value = 0, message = "The product unit must not be less than zero.")
    private int unitInStock;
    private String productManufacturer;

    @Transient
    private MultipartFile productImage;

    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductCategory() {
        return productCategory;
    }

    public void setProductCategory(String productCategory) {
        this.productCategory = productCategory;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public double getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(double productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public String getProductCondition() {
        return productCondition;
    }

    public void setProductCondition(String productCondition) {
        this.productCondition = productCondition;
    }

    public String getProductStatus() {
        return productStatus;
    }

    public void setProductStatus(String productStatus) {
        this.productStatus = productStatus;
    }

    public int getUnitInStock() {
        return unitInStock;
    }

    public void setUnitInStock(int unitInStock) {
        this.unitInStock = unitInStock;
    }

    public String getProductManufacturer() {
        return productManufacturer;
    }

    public void setProductManufacturer(String productManufacturer) {
        this.productManufacturer = productManufacturer;
    }

    public MultipartFile getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public void setProductImage(MultipartFile productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }
}
```

my productdaoimpl:-

```
package com.emusicstore.dao.impl;

import com.emusicstore.dao.ProductDao;
import com.emusicstore.model.Product;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Le on 1/6/2016.
 */

@Repository
@Transactional
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(product);
        session.flush();
    }

    public void editProduct(Product product) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(product);
        session.flush();
    }

    public Product getProductById(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class, id);
        session.flush();

        return product;
    }

    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Product");
        List<Product> products = query.list();
        session.flush();

        return products;
    }

    public void deleteProduct (int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.delete(getProductById(id));
        session.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like you are passing `NULL` to product id, error message is clear NULL not allowed for column "PRODUCTID".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not set the value for `productId` and it pass null in it.  To autoincrement the `productId` you can change `GenerationType.AUTO` to `GenerationType.IDENTITY`.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int productId;
```

Hope this will work for you.